# unable to fetch data from ssrs to php web page

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

while trying to fetch the data from ssrs version(2008 R2) to the php web page i am getting following error:

```
 SSRSReportException Object
 [errorCode] => rsAccessDenied
 [errorDescription] => The permissions granted to user 'PC\Phpdemouser' 
 are insufficient for performing this operation.
 [soapFault] => SoapFault Object
 [message:protected] => System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 
 The permissions granted to user 'PC\Phpdemouser' are insufficient for 
 performing this operation
```

what could be wrong so that it's giving this error.

Comment: Are you able to open the report with a browser on the report server with the account `PC\Phpdemouser`?

Comment: I have not used the PC\phpdemouser. When I have changed it to the system user I am able to open the report in php webpage. Thanks for your suggestion. I want to make the report responsive what settings I should make to the report server?

Comment: You can cache the reports if you have a limited set of parameters, you can also optimize the query. This would have to be a separate question because it is off topic. Also note that you will have to include more details because it is also too broad.